# How to reorder rows using SQL (not swap)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to reorder items in a table as showed in the following example:

```
Original:
Id    Pos (int)
---------
a     1
b     2
c     3
d     4
e     5

I need this result after moving d to the second row:
Id    Pos (int)
---------
a     1
b     3
c     4
d     2
e     5
```

As you can see, it is not a simple swap and I need to increase position by 1 after insert position, and leave the rows before insert the same. I tried to resolve it this way:

```
UPDATE [Table] SET Pos = 2 WHERE Id = 'd'

MERGE INTO [Table] T USING
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Pos) AS Position, Id FROM [Table]
) S
ON T.Id = S.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Pos = S.Position;
```

However after update two rows have the same position. It will probably not be sorted correctly.

You can generate the example data using the script below:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table] (
  Id char NOT NULL,
  Pos int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id])
)
GO
INSERT INTO [Table] (Id, Pos) VALUES ('a', 1),('b', 2),('c', 3),('d', 4),('e', 5)
```

Comment: There's not really enough information here to understand what the problem is. Reading the SQL alone I would expect that the merge statement would not have any impact as it would be continually writing out the existing position. Can you include a full sample including a create table statement, inserting some sample data, and include the existing script behind that so we can test locally?

Comment: You should describe better what the rules are related to "reorder". Most probably the best you can do is find a way to order the key-column the way you want to see it (even an ugly solution) then re-number everything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DECLARE @id CHAR(1) = 'd';
DECLARE @newpos INT = 2;
DECLARE @oldpos INT;

BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SELECT @oldpos = Pos FROM Table WHERE id = @id;
  IF @newpos < @oldpos 
    UPDATE #Table SET Pos = Pos + 1 
     WHERE Pos >= @newpos AND Pos < @oldpos;
  ELSE
    UPDATE #Table SET Pos = Pos - 1 
     WHERE Pos >= @newpos AND Pos > @oldpos;

  UPDATE #Table SET Pos = @newpos
   WHERE Id = @id;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Well this script isnt perfect, I have to run it twice to make sure the final order is achieved.